# Implementing voice chat in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, voip, voice

I'm creating a small web chat application using ASP.NET, text chat is almost done using Ajax,SQL Server but now I'm going to create a voice system also. I've googled a lot but with no real luck, what are my options? Silverlight? VoIP? or something else? I've worked a lot with SL, is it my only way of implementing voice chat in web? can I use pure ASP.NET to have voice chat? how can I use TCP/IP for voice communication? is there any online sample showing voice chat or communication?

Comment: I have no real experience with it myself,but Web RTC is what you want to research.

Comment: I have found this discussion thread with info that might help you. They use silverlight on the client side to access audio resources: http://forums.asp.net/t/1777552.aspx?Voice+chat+in+asp+net+web+application+

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***assembly*** for voice chat should you want to, but it's very hard. I can't give a good answer without knowing how well you know ASP.NET/C#, but VoIP isn't hard to implement *Normally*.

Basically, you need a codec on each end, and a protocol to transfer packets - encoded obviously - from one end to the other (Mostly UDP).

Now, When I say Normally I mean in a perfect world where network issues - mostly related to NAT - don't exist.

Also you will need something other than ASP.NET, Like a plugin (Silverlight should do, but something mainstream like flash or java are recommended) to get a bit more control of the client's PC (Microphone, speakers).

I quite doubt you can do this alone, no offence. Therefore I would recommend using a library like SIP Communicator, [Here's a Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138484/Simple-SIP-VOIP-based-phone-in-C) and [Another](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17048/Examples-to-create-your-Conferencing-System-in-NET).

Comment: Thanks I'll do what you said, I'm not going to re-invent the wheel, I use existing tools like SIP, I can everything with ASP.NET, although I know it is a server side technology and I do need something client-side (like JS, SL or flash). Can you give me some links or samples?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet sorry, I didn't get you, what do you mean by "I can everything with ASP.NET, although I know it is a server side technology and I do need something client-side "

Comment: I mean I have no problem with ASP.NET or even JS, I'm just looking for ways to implement a simple (even one-way) voice chat

Comment: @Ali_dotNet if this answers your question please accept it as an answer